# Angular: Como ejecutar una función cuando se termine de renderizar un list en el HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Estoy aplicando este código en el HTML de Angular

```
<div *ngIf="similarMovies" class="col-12">
      <div class="bg-dark p-3 my-3 text-white">
        <h2 class="font-weight-light">Peliculas relacionadas</h2>
        <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center">
          <div
            id="recipeCarousel"
            class="carousel slide"
            data-bs-ride="carousel"
          >
            <div class="carousel-inner text-center" role="listbox">
              <div
                *ngFor="let movie of similarMovies; let index = index"
                [ngClass]="{ active: index === 1 }"
                class="carousel-item"
              >
                <div class="col-md-3 p-1">
                  <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
                    <img [src]="movie.poster_path" class="card-img" alt="..." />
                    <div class="card-img-overlay">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a
              class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut"
              href="#recipeCarousel"
              role="button"
              data-bs-slide="prev"
            >
              <span
                class="carousel-control-prev-icon"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
            </a>
            <a
              class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut"
              href="#recipeCarousel"
              role="button"
              data-bs-slide="next"
            >
              <span
                class="carousel-control-next-icon"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

El cual me renderiza el siguiente carrusel de imágenes, la información la obtengo de una Api por lo cual debe esperar para obtener y listar la información en el HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que para que me dibuje el list en el carrusel, como se muestra en la imagen  implemento esta función

```
sliderSimilarMovies() {
    const items =
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');

    items.forEach((el: any) => {
      const minPerSlide = 4;
      let next = el.nextElementSibling;
      for (var i = 1; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
        if (!next) {
          // wrap carousel by using first child
          next = items[0];
        }
        let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true) as any;
        el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0]);
        next = next.nextElementSibling;
      }
    });
  }
```

Ya la agregue al AfterViewInit pero no me lo renderiza como espero, obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La única solución que encontré es agregar la función al obtener los datos de la api

```
getSimilarMovies(movieId: string) {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.apiService.getSimilarMovies(movieId).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          this.similarMovies = response.slice(0, 10);
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.sliderSimilarMovies();
          }, 2000);
        },
      })
    );
  }
```

¿Abra otra manera de realizar esto de una manera ideal, sin un setTimeout?

Comment: En ves de ejecutar el this.sliderSimilarMovies(); en el next, puedes hacerlo en el complete, y así cuando ya el next no reciba mas información, se ejecuta el complete y ejecutaría el método.

Comment: Ya lo probé pero sigue igual, me imagino que es por lo mismo de que primero tiene que renderizar el html para obtener los .carousel-items